# How to disable Permissions in DRF views?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to disable all django things that use default database. Admin, session, messages etc. won't work, but it is acceptable. I want to make my api server fully stateless.

P.S. Just turning off all the middlewares and apps does not work.

P.S.S. I know I can use FastApi or smt, but i want django(drf)

I tried remove all the middlewares and apps, but when i try to go my pages i got an error

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # 'django.contrib.auth',
    # 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    # 'django.contrib.sessions',
    # 'django.contrib.messages',
    # 'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    "restapi.apps.RestapiConfig",

    "rest_framework",
    "corsheaders",
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    # 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    # 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    # 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]
```

Error:

```
RuntimeError at /api/savedfilters/
Model class django.contrib.auth.models.Permission doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/savedfilters/
Django Version: 4.2.6
Exception Type: RuntimeError
Exception Value:    
Model class django.contrib.auth.models.Permission doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
Exception Location: C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\ndbackend-_IiuFZN4-py3.10\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py, line 134, in __new__
Raised during:  restapi.views.SavedFilterView
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\ndbackend-_IiuFZN4-py3.10\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.0
```

**P.S. Found that DRF uses Permissions by defaul, permission uses ContentTypes. I need a way to disable drf checking permissions. Custom authecation backend did not work.**

Answer (score 0):

You can set an empty list for default permission and authentication classes, in your settings:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': []
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [],
}
```

It should disable any authnentication code for all views.

Note, you can disable authentication for specific view by set these two parameters directly in the View class:

```py
class CustomApiView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
```

Comment: Nah, did not work for me. I tried both ways